# Spring Boot bean conditional on @ConfigurationProperties value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot gives us typed configuration objects using the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation. One of the advantages is getting property name completion in the IDE for free when using the Spring Boot annotation processor. Another would be: validation.

Now, I'd like to make a bean conditional on the value of a property. Actually, I have two implementations of an interface and this property tells me which one should be used. I could implement it like this:

**ImplementationA.java**

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "foo.bar", havingValue = "a")
public class ImplementationA implements SomeInterface { ... }
```

**ImplementationB.java**

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "foo.bar", havingValue = "b")
public class ImplementationB implements SomeInterface { ... }
```

**application.yml**

```
foo:
  bar: "a"
```

However, I'd then lose the advantage of typed configuration. So I'd like to declare this property in a `@ConfigurationProperties` object:

**FooProperties.java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
public class FooProperties {

    private String bar;


    public String getBar() { ... }

    public void setBar(String bar) { ... }
}
```

This would still work, but when I declare a default value for `bar` in this class, it would obviously not be picked up by `@ConditionalOnProperty` as this annotation operates against the `Environment` directly (as designed). So perhaps it'd be best not to mix these concepts.

### So the question is...

Would there be a way to have a conditional bean based on a value in a `@ConfigurationProperties` object? Preferable using some `@Conditional` annotation and without creating a `@Configuration` bean, as that would mean boilerplate code.

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties` comes way below `@Conditional...` Annotations in the component scan chain.  Hence I don't think it is possible. All the `@Conditional` annotations like `@Condition`, `@ConditionalOnProperty` and `@ConditionalOnExpression` are executed before `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: Can't you use both? Create the FooProperties as before, but add a static constant with the default value and reference that in the "havingValue" propertie of ConditionalOnProperty

Comment: Have you ever found answer for your question ?

Answer (score 2):

As proposed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2282), you could create the ConfigurationProperties object manually in your @Conditional like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder
...
YourConfigurationPropertiesClass config = Binder.get(context.getEnvironment())
.bind("your.properties.prefix", YourConfigurationPropertiesClass.class).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not be as sexy but a potential solution could be to Autowire your Configuration into a SomeInterfaceConfiguration that creates provides the service implementation based on the FooProperties.

i.e.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeInterfaceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public SomeInterface someInterface(FooProperties fooProperties){
        if("a".equals(fooProperties.getBar()){
            return SomeInterfaceImplementationA();
        } else {
            return SomeInterfaceImplementationB();
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to use profiles but it is different to your desired solution.
i.e. Have a default implementation.

```
@Component
public class ImplementationA 

@Profile("b")
@Primary
@Component
public class ImplementationB
```